# Run from command line, Wrong Name error

Tags: java, command-line, javac

I want to run a Java project from the command line which I start using a batch file, but I get the wrong name error.

The directory setup:

- srcMVC

  - bin (folder with .class files)
  - src (folder with .java files)
  - Batch file

Batch file:

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin
javac src\model\*.java -d bin -cp src
javac src\controller\*.java -d bin -cp src
javac src\view\*.java -d bin -cp src
javac src\main\*.java -d bin -cp src
PAUSE
java bin\main.Main
PAUSE
```

Compiling works, but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bin\main/Main (wrong name: main/Main)
```

Any suggestions?

---

```
package main;

// omitted imports

public class Main {
    // omitted variables

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // omitted implementation   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of `main()` under `main.java`

Comment: what is output of `dir` inside `main` folder?

Comment: java -cp bin bin\main.main

Comment: @HardikMishra public static void main(String[] args) { }

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov the main folder which includes the .class file?

Comment: @MiguelPrz Could not find or load main class error.

Comment: yes in folder with classes.

Comment: javac would create class files in same folder unless you move it manually.

Comment: -d stands for the destination for the .class files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statement resolved my error:

```
java -cp bin; main.Main
```

Answer (score 2):

`NoClassDefFoundError` in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

For example if we have a method call from a class or accessing any static member of a Class and that class is not available during run-time then JVM will throw `NoClassDefFoundError`.

By default Java `CLASSPATH` points to current directory denoted by "." and it will look for any class only in current directory.

So, You need to add other paths to `CLASSPATH` at run time. Read more [Setting the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

`java -cp bin main.Main`

where `Main.class` contains `public static void main(String []arg)`

Comment: I have changed the classname to Main. I ran your code and I thing you forgot a semicolon after view.
java -cp bin;model;controller;view bin\main.Main

Comment: I see as you are compiling with `-d`. Your all classes should be under "bin" directory. So, you need to add "bin" to your class path why don't you show some code and files used in `Main` class

Comment: I included the content of Main.java, see question.

Comment: Why did you omit import ? please include them

Comment: It shouldn't be a path here, it is a class name: java -cp bin main.Main it will search for main.Main under the classpath you specified (bin). Two different things.

Comment: @shuangwhywhy: I edited post after OP's comment, will edit the post. :)

Answer (score 1):

you are wrongly exicuting java bin\main.main

main() is your main method but you should supply java interpreter the `Class Name` which implements main()

So if your class name is Test and file name is Test.java which has main() method

`java Test`

if your Test.java/Test class in is package my.test e.g - `package com.my.test;`

than, `java com.my.test.Test`

hope you got it !!

Comment: Helped it . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`java bin/main.Main` is wrong, you must specify `-cp` here:

```
java main.Main -cp bin
```

Here the first argument is the **class name** which should be found in the classpaths, **rather than the class file location**. And `-cp` just adds the logical path to classpaths. You should make the root of your project searchable in the classpath.

and for those javac commands, you have already specified the correct path, so you don't need `-cp src`. The difference here is the javac command uses logical path for `.java` files, while using java command you could only specify the path in `-cp` attribute.

You could also execute `java main.Main` without `-cp` if you enter the directory `bin`:

```
cd bin
java main.Main
```

Since the current path will be automatically be searched by java as a classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class called Main you have to run it with this command:

```
java bin\Main
```

It will call your main method.

Answer (score 0):

Java run time (in your case the java.exe command), takes the class file name that containst the main() method as input. I guess you should be invoking it as "java bin\main" assuming there is a main.class which has a public static void main (String[]) method defined.

Note: General practice is to capitalize the first literal of any class name.

Comment: bin is a folder. main is a package. main is the .class file.

folder>package>file