# "can't find main class" error in terminal but not in eclipse

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

This program take real life objects and its weights and sorts it based on alphebatical order and then number-wise

But the problem is that when I run this app in Eclipse (haven't tried in NetBeans), it runs fine, but when I compile and try to run it in terminal, it doesn't work and comes with error, 
"could not find main class"

Keep in mind my java file and class file are in the same folder, so the directory is not the problem

```
public class testMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //makes a new multidimensial array
    //the first dimension holds the name of the object 
    //the second dimension holds the weight
    //the 4's in this case show the maximum space the array can hold
    String[][] objectList = new String[4][4];

    objectList[1][0] = "Teapot";
    objectList[0][1] = String.valueOf(1);

    objectList[2][0] = "Chesterfield";
    objectList[2][2] = String.valueOf(120);

    objectList[3][0] = "Laptop";
    objectList[3][3] = String.valueOf(6);

    //printing the array
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3;) {
            System.out.println(objectList[i][j].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

By request: 
In the command line I put,

```
cd /Users/username/Desktop/JavaProjects
javac ojArray.java
(After it compiled)
java ojArray.class
```

Comment: Show what did you do in the command line, please.

Comment: @duffymo -- I think that's exactly what the OP is trying to learn.

Comment: @ntalbs I put in there now

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752485/problem-running-java-code-through-command-line

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625558/java-run-from-command-line-wrong-name-error/14625638#14625638

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile/run a Java program in terminal, you do the following:

1. Go to the directory that your program is in (you can use the `cd` "change directory" command to do so).

   - On Windows, to get to your desktop, it would be: `cd C:\Users\YourLogin\Desktop`
   - On Mac, it would be: `cd ~/Users/YourLogin/Desktop`
2. To compile, type `javac NameOfProgram.java`, eg `javac testMain.java`
3. To run, type `java NameOfProgram`, eg `java testMain`

Comment: +1 Very good answer. Just to reiterate, you do *not* type the ".class" extension for step 3. You *only* specify the Java class name, not full the file name for the class.

Comment: @MonadNewb yeah, I just realized that after I saw the answer. I feel like an idiot now.

Comment: @user2034125, it's okay.  We were all there at some point.  Good luck!