# Consoles in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I do have some serious troubles understanding the console in java. I am running Eclipse, and I wanted to write a small program which prompts a few text messages to the console and receives a few strings as input arguments from it. Problem is: When I run my program, it opens the command line window properly, but my outputs are only printed on the Eclipse-Console.
In some way, I do understand why this is the case. The Command Line Windows expects commands, and not just some kind of a string or something. But how do i manage to output my Strings into the Command Line Window and read Strings from it, and not just commands.
Or am I doing it the wrong way? Do I have to open another "Console" where all my messages will be prompted and from which i can read strings a user wrote?

This is the code i use to open a command line window on start:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "cmd", "/C",
            "start", "cmd" }).start();
    System.out.println(process.waitFor());
```

**Edit: I did still not manage to get this to working. Somehow, when I compiled the program, and I run it, it properly opens a command window, but no messages are posted there. Seems like "System.out.println("xxx") does not have any effect on this window.**

Comment: Basically there will be single console in Eclipse. If you run your program it ask/prompt for some input on same console. After Enter hit you will get your output on same console. That's it..

Comment: I'd say the intended/normal way would be to use the Eclipse console when you're running from inside Eclipse and the command line console when running from the command line. You should have to change anything for this to work, so we'd need to see your code in order to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "console" specified by your program, but an `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` for input, output and error output. When you run your program from windows, these streams are bound to a command window, and if you run it in eclipse, they will be associated to the eclipse console. To give a more obscure example, ff you were running it through ssh, the streams would be associated to ssh, and ssh associated to your command window, and so on.

So, you're not doing anything wrong, you just need to run the program from the command line if you want stdout and stdin to come from that command window.

How do you open a command window, by the way?

Comment: Well when I export my Program as an executable .jar, the command line window opens when i click it (program opens in automatically), but there are still no outputs shown in the window, and it still expects commands from the user.
And when i open a command line window manually, i do it via Windows+R -> "cmd"

Comment: Ok, *that* is weird. If you double click and a new cmd window opens, which is awaiting input (i.e. stdin is associated to it) then stdout and stderr should *also* be there (i.e. the printouts should appear)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read through this page:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/JavaTutorial/NOTES/JavaIO_Scanner.html

Basically what you need to is create the input stream, tell the user to input something, and then get the input. E.g.

```
private static Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Put your input here: ");

    String inputValue = newScanner.nextLine(); 

    System.out.println(inputValue);

}
```

Just remember to import the scanner library!

Comment: now i added the code i use to open a command line window on program start. maybe this is causing my troubles?
of course, when i run my program in eclipse, i can use the eclipse console. but when i export it as executable .jar and run the program, it opens the command line, but nothing happens in it.

Comment: Just following this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265883/cant-find-main-class-error-in-terminal-but-not-in-eclipse I was able to get this running through the command line with no problem. I hope that helps